# Horizontal and vertical scrolling image gallery (Android)

Tags: android, scroll

I need some advice/ideas on how to proceed.

I am planning to make an image gallery with both horizontal and vertical scrolling. The idea is to scroll thru the category images horizontal and when at a category browse thru that category by scrolling vertical (down) without clicking.

Johan

Comment: i have found this http://profi.co/android-horizontal-list-view-library-with-item-scroll/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library.

**Features:**

- Multithread image loading
- Possibility of wide tuning ImageLoader's configuration (thread executors, downlaoder, decoder, memory and disc cache, display image options, and others)
- Possibility of image caching in memory and/or on device's file sysytem (or SD card)
- Possibility to "listen" loading process
- Possibility to customize every display image call with separated options
- Widget support

**Sample:**

[image]